# Handheld media type in css vs another domain or subdomain for mobile enabled site?

Tags: css, xhtml, mobile

While Handheld option is available in CSS then why some people use different subdomain and make different site for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second what Justin Niessner said. Also, the mobile version of a site is usually structured differently from the "main page". Other content may be displayed on the front page, an only a selection of menu items, or a whole different menu altogether. Videos have to be embedded differently, images as well, Javascript effects altered and so on. Using different style sheets mostly just won't cut it.

Comment: So is it better to make different site for mobile instead of using handheld css?

Comment: Well, that depends on whether your site has the structural differences I listed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to make the distinction more apparent to the user.

That, and the Blackberry Browser (and possibly the iPhone) identifies itself as a mobile device (depending on settings)...but could theoretically be able to display the full page. Using CSS, you're also depending a lot on the mobile browser to do the correct thing with your page.

You'll provide a much more reliable interface if you let the user specify the experience, not the site.